# JQuery Form remains static - page doesn't validate on the fly

Tags: php, jquery, forms, contacts, contact-form

I'm having some problems with my contact form using jquery.

I've used this same code several times before but this time I've changed divs and classes
to have meaningful names.

Everything works, it's just that when you press submit, you are physically taken to send.php instead of the data being placed in the placeholder div.

It's driving me mad so I was wondering if another few pairs of eyes could spot something?

Thanks,

Martin

All JS includes in the head of the page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.anchor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.2.6.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.highlight').hover(function(){
        $(this).children().addClass('datahighlight');
    },function(){
        $(this).children().removeClass('datahighlight');
    });
  });
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
$('contactform').addEvent('submit', function(e) {
new Event(e).stop();
var log = $('form_results').empty().addClass('ajax-loading');
this.send({
update: log,
onComplete: function() {
log.removeClass('ajax-loading');
                       }
                    });
                });
            });
</script>
```

Contact section:

```
        <h2 class="contact">Contact Us</h2>

        <p> Some text</p>

        <div id="log">
            <div id="form_results">
                <!-- SPANNER -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <form method="post" id="contactform" action="send.php"> 

            <p><label for="name">Name</label></p> 
            <input type="text" id=name name=name placeholder="First and last name" tabindex="1" /> 

            <p><label for="email">Email</label></p> 
            <input type="text" id=email name=email placeholder="example@domain.com" tabindex="2" /> 

            <p><label for="comment">Your Message</label></p> 
            <textarea name="comment" id=comment name=comment placeholder="Comments" tabindex="4"></textarea> 

            <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Send Message" /> 

        </form> 


    </section>
```

Send.php:

```
<?php

function alpha_numeric($str)
{
    return ( ! preg_match("/^([-a-z0-9])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}

function valid_email($str)
{
    return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}

if ($_POST['name']=='' || strlen($_POST['name'])<3)
{
    $errors[] = 'Please include your name, it helps when contacting you! [needs to be more than 3 characters]';
}

if (valid_email($_POST['email'])==FALSE)
{
    $errors[] = 'At least put a real e-mail address!';
}

if ($_POST['comment']=='' || strlen($_POST['comment'])<3)
{
    $errors[] = 'Please write something, otherwise it\'s pointless contacting us!';
}

if(is_array($errors))
{
    echo '<div id="error-margin">';
    echo '<p class="error"><b>Can\'t send it for the following reasons:</b></p><br />';
    while (list($key,$value) = each($errors))
    {
        echo '<span class="error">'.$value.'</span><br /><br />';
    }
    echo'</div>';
}
else {
    // do something here----store to db, send email
    echo'<div id="success">';
    echo '<p><b>It worked!</b></p>';
    echo '<span>Thanks for contacting us! We\'ll be in touch soon</span>';
    echo'</div>';

    $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']); //sender's name
    $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']); //sender's email


    // The subject
    $subject  = "Message from 4playtheband.co.uk "; //The default subject. Will appear by default in all messages.

    $msg  = "From :   $name \r\n";  // add sender's name to the message
    $msg .= "e-mail : $email \r\n\n";  // add sender's email to the message
    $msg .= "---Message--- \r\n\n\t".stripslashes($_POST['comment'])."\r\n\n";  // the message itself

    // Extras:
    // Display user information such as Ip address and browsers information...
    $msg .= "---User information--- \r\n\n"; //Title
    $msg .= "User IP Address: ".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."\r\n"; //Sender's IP
    $msg .= "Browser: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]."\r\n"; //User agent
    $msg .= "Page User Came From: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; //Referrer

    // Send!
    (mail('someone', $subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n"));

}
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - **DEMO & SOURCE:** https://so.lucafilosofi.com/jquery-form-remains-static-page-doesnt-validate-on-the-fly/

you are using jquery, so there is no need to use `window.addEvent('domready', function(){`

you js code should look like this:

```
$('#contactform').submit(function() {
    var query = $(this).serialize();
    $('#form_results').fadeOut(500).addClass('ajax-loading');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "send.php",
        data: query,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#form_results').removeClass('ajax-loading').html(data).fadeIn(500);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to suggest this but the page is still behaving the same way.

Because the action and method are declared in the js code, does that mean you can take out the action and method from the `<form>` tag?

Comment: I have updated with DEMO & SOURCE my code works and also your PHP code work thus you may have some js conflicts somewhere. let me know.

Comment: perfect, thank you so much. The only difference I cans see is that you merged the two pieces of javascript so don't know why that made it work all of a sudden.

Do you have any tips how to make the div fade in and out?

Comment: i have updated the demo with fadeIn() & fadeOut() take a look at it.

Comment: absolutely fantastic, thank you very much for your help.

The one final question I have is, once you submit the form, you can simply keep clicking the button to constantly generate e-mails :/

Do you have any suggestions - e.g. hide the form or reset it once it has been submitted?

Comment: you have many option to prevent the form submission abuse, you can use one of the following: php sessions, chapta code, disable the submit button, setting cockies and many other i guess...! ;) happy coding Martin.

Answer (score 1):

`window.addEvent('domready',...` is from MooTool. Since you use Jquery you may have to add

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

before. Oh and it seems that FancyUpload only work with MooTool, don't forget to include that.

Comment: tried it with `$('.form_results')` and `$('.contactform')` but that didn't work either.

Comment: See the edit, I think you got some libraries messing with each other

Comment: thanks for noticing that, because on my other pages I was using MooTools I copied my existing form code over, forgetting that I was using jQuery...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i typically use preventDefault() like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $('contactform').addEvent('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var log = $('form_results').empty().addClass('ajax-loading');
      this.send({
        update: log,
        onComplete: function() {
          log.removeClass('ajax-loading');
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you, just realised the code I was using was from my mooTools form when on my new site I am using jQuery, sorry for the confusion but thanks for helping.